# what does tab key mean?

Tags: tabs, keyboard

This is my code:

```
String s = "This\tis\tmy\tsmall\texample\tstring\twhich\tI'm\tgoing\tto\tuse\tfor\tpattern\tmatching.";
    System.out.println(s);
```

it printed

```
This    is  my  small   example string  which   I'm going   to  use for pattern matching.
```

How many spaces does the "\t" key occupy? Sometime it occupy one space,sometime it occupy two spaces, Sometime it occupy five spaces.why?Any help would be appreciate.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is the concept of tab size (usually 8), which is configurable, but that does not directly determine how much visual space a given tab uses.

If you enter a tab, it moves to the next tab position. For example from 3 -> 8.  Or from 6 -> 8. It does not move a fixed amount of spaces, it depends on where the "cursor" is at the moment.

In a publishing/layout context, where you have non-proportional fonts, the tab size may not even be a number of characters, but rather a physical width (like an inch).

Answer (score 0):

You should use " " instead of "/t".

A tab in a string usually occupies either 4 or 8 column spaces. Here, these column spaces also include the word length. If your word length is less than 4, it would take 4 column spaces otherwise 8 spaces.

Eg-
'The\t' is equivalent to 'The*' and 'small\t' to 'small***'

Comment: Why is HTML appropriate here?

Comment: Thank you very much.I understand.

Comment: I see.There are some concepts, word length, tab size and the length of spaces of tab appear.And they have some relationship.
tabOccupySize < tabSize and (tabOccupySize+myWord)%tabSize == 0

Comment: yes, @fengsmith this concept is exactly the same as I was talking about

Comment: @Thilo HTML is not appropriate here. Thanks for pointing that out. I have made the edit.

Comment: tabOccupySize <= tabSize and (tabOccupySize+myWord)%tabSize == 0